# How to retrieve last week data from database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new in android. I don't know much more about sqlite database and date. I just want to get last week data from database. I have tried below code by following some material. I'm not getting, should i declare date as date datatype,if i use date() method in query. If someone help me by some code with explanation that will be very helpful to me.
I'm creating table by following way:

```
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
        "(" + ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
            + AMOUNT + " real, "
            + PAYER_NAME + " text, " 
            + NOTE + " text, "
            + DATE + " text " + ")";
```

Here i'm inserting data

```
  public void addInformation(DataProvider provider) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ID, provider.getId());
    values.put(AMOUNT, provider.getMoney());
    values.put(PAYER_NAME, provider.getName());
    values.put(NOTE, provider.getDesc());
    values.put(DATE,provider.getDate());
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
    }
```

And by the following query i'm trying to retrieve my data

```
SELECT * FROM income_table WHERE date BETWEEN date('now', '-6 days') AND date('now')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me

```
SELECT id,ReleaseDateStart
FROM TK1 
WHERE CAST (strftime('%W', ReleaseDateStart) AS Integer)  = CAST (strftime('%W', datetime('now', 'localtime')) AS Integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you set wrong date in your database or this will work for you.

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM income_table WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', '-6 days') AND datetime('now', 'localtime')");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try making your date format as `YYYY-MM-DD` instead of "yyyy-MM-dd" and add local time in your query if it still doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM income_table WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', '-6 days') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');
```

Comment: `DD` returns the `day of year`, i.e. 1~365.

Comment: @Rahid what is returned from the query?